# Format number inside image bubble

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm having some trouble understanding how to properly align items in top of each other:

So I have the following VStack:

```
VStack(spacing: 0) {
    Text("\(placeC.places.count)")
    Image("map-pin-full-cluster-1")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(.brown)
} //: END VStack
```

Which produces the following output:

[image]

What is the best way to have the number inside the circle? Is there a recommended SwiftUI builder that you all use that I can explore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would use an `.overlay`:

```
Image("map-pin-full-cluster-1")
    .renderingMode(.template)
    .resizable()
    .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
    .foregroundColor(.brown)
    .overlay(alignment: .top) {
        Text("\(placeC.places.count)")
    }
```

or a `ZStack`:

```
ZStack(alignment: .top) {  // other alignments: .center, .bottom, .leading, .trailing
    Image("map-pin-full-cluster-1")
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .resizable()
        .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        .foregroundColor(.brown)
    Text("\(placeC.places.count)")
        .padding(.top, 4)  // adjust this to move the text up/down
}
```

Comment: The ZStack worked out perfectly, thank you! I will accept this answer in 5 minutes, I have to look into how ZStack made this work.

Comment: If I need to push the number down a little bit using ZStack, what would be appropriate approach? Now the number is touching the top of the image and I just need to push it down a little bit.

Comment: Use the .offset(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) modifier on the view. It will help you move the view away from it's original position.

Comment: `Text("\(placeC.places.count)").padding(.top, 4)`